# MD5 hash from for loop

Tags: hashsum

I have the following string: `"VGxkTk1GcHFTWGRhUjBacFkycENhMWx0VFRWT1IxazBUMVJXYUZwSFNUQmlWR1JxVGtSVmVVOVZjR3RhYWtFOQ%3D%3D"`

and a for loop:

```
for(var i=0,k=3,l=643; (i<=20 && l>200) || k>8;i++,k--){
    console.count();
    }
```

how to get md5 ?

function show(){
    var cookie = "VGxkTk1GcHFTWGRh UjBacFkycENhMWx0 VFRWT1IxazBUMVJX YUZwSFNUQmlWR1Jx VGtSVmVVOVZjR3Rh YWtFOQ%3D%3D";
    for(var i=0,k=3,l=643; (i<=20 && l>200) || k>8;i++,k--){
    console.count();
    }

```
document.write("Here is your cookie: "+cookie+" It's md5, isn't!");

// To solve this  you must know about md5 hash
// Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 and read about it ;)
```

}

Comment: The md5sum of what?

Comment: MD5 of what, the string? How is the loop connected to the string? What kind of language is the loop written in (if it's relevant at all to the question, I don't know)?

Comment: I have a cat and a rutebega.  How to get aeroplane?

Comment: function show(){
    var cookie = "VGxkTk1GcHFTWGRh UjBacFkycENhMWx0 VFRWT1IxazBUMVJX YUZwSFNUQmlWR1Jx VGtSVmVVOVZjR3Rh YWtFOQ%3D%3D";
    for(var i=0,k=3,l=643; (i<=20 && l>200) || k>8;i++,k--){
    console.count();
    }
    
 document.write("Here is your cookie: "+cookie+" It's md5, isn't!");
    
 // To solve this  you must know about md5 hash
    // Go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 and read about it ;)
   
}

Comment: If this is an assignment of some sort, I really hope it's not asking you to _implement MD5 by yourself_, but to find the library implementation of MD5 in whatever language it is your using (javascript?) and call that routine. Maybe do a search on "javascript MD5"?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the string could be base64-encoded, then URL-encoded... the "%3D%3D" at the end would be two equals signs.

Whatever it's worth, passing it through a base64 decoder results in another string that looks like valid base64 encoding. A total of three passes through the base64 decoder and you'll get something quite different-looking...

```
echo "VGxkTk1GcHFTWGRhUjBacFkycENhMWx0VFRWT1IxazBUMVJXYUZwSFNUQmlWR1JxVGtSVmVVOVZjR3RhYWtFOQ==" \ 
  | base64 -d | base64 -d | base64 -d |od -t x1z
```

results in:

```
0000000 35 63 34 66 32 30 64 61 62 72 30 64 62 63 39 34  >5c4f20dabr0dbc94<
0000020 66 38 39 35 61 64 62 34 6d 37 63 34 35 32 39 4a  >f895adb4m7c4529J<
0000040 64 66 30                                         >df0<
```

Suddenly we get all lower-case characters and numbers. And trying to base64-decode that further results in some unprintable characters and then an "invalid input" from the base64 decoder. So maybe this means something, maybe it doesn't.

It has three more characters than a standard MD5 checksum... and those three characters are all outside the list of valid md5sum characters: "r", "m" and "J". Remove those, and you'll get a hexadecimal numbert that *could* in theory be a MD5 checksum of *something*.

Comment: Nice detective work there Sherlock.